# Como posso pegar os resultados das loterias?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api

Pesquisei por API's da lotérica para pegar os resultados dos concursos, infelizmente não consegui achar nenhuma.

A resposta do `@fpg1503` consegue ler apenas o resultado do jogo atual, gostaria de saber se é possível pegar os resultados dos jogos anteriores também.

Comment: Tem [isso](http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/loteriafederal), ajuda?

Comment: Muito boa a pergunta. Não entendi o porque dos negativos. +1.

Comment: No final da página dos resultados de cada tipo de jogo (megasena, lotofácil...) a Caixa disponibiliza um arquivo com o resultado de todos os jogos: Exemplos: http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena e http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil. Você pode fazer uma carga inicial destes arquivos para a sua base de dados, e ir atualizando a base usando a API da resposta ou ainda fazendo carga diferencial dos tais arquivos.

Comment: @Caffé a idéia é boa, mas eles mandam um HTML sem graça dentro desse zip. Teria que se improvisar um crawler pra tirar os dados de lá, ou fazer alguma outra "acrobacia". Mas ao menos é oficial.

Comment: Quatro anos depois da pergunta e a Caixa ainda não disponibilizou uma API oficial para obtenção dos resultados de loterias.
Fiz uma classlybrary em C# há algum tempo e já precisei modificar várias vezes por alterações fetas no site. Não sei se ela ainda está funcionando, mas o link para ela está [aqui](https://github.com/carlosribeiro1987/ResultadoLoteriasCaixa-CSharp). Sei que não é a melhor opção (programo por hobby), mas na época serviu aos meus objetivos. Amanhã farei alguns testes, caso tenha tempo. Se não estiver mais funcionando tentarei consertar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT (29/08/2016): Esta API foi tirada do ar**

Como mencionado pelo [Fernando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2998/fernando) uma API para ver o resultado das lotéricas pode ser vista [aqui](http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/loteriafederal/json).

Basta fazer um `GET` para `http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/loteriafederal/json` e parsear o JSON.

## PHP

### Se `allow_url_fopen` estiver ativo

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/loteriafederal/json'));
```

### Se não estiver

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/loteriafederal/json');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$json = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);
```

## jQuery com Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/loterias/loteriafederal/json",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Não entendi o motivo dos -1

Comment: Estamos no final de Agosto, 7 meses depois que postou. Esperei esse tempo para responder o motivo dos negativos.  Você pode ver que a fonte de consulta do seu código não existe mais. Isso porque não era uma fonte oficial mas apenas uma fonte terceira sem garantia de manutenção. Na ocasião não negativei. Mas agora dou um negativo. Não fiquei torcendo para acontecer. Apenas esperei pelo óbvio... 404 not found

Answer (score 15):

Um exemplo usando php-curl para obter o resultado do jogo mais recente da Mega-Sena, diretamente do site oficial.

O script obtém os dados do site oficial onde é necessário ativar o cookie. Por isso é necessário setar `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` e `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`, sem os quais, o token que redireciona não carrega a página.

O parâmetro `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` precisa estar como `true` para que permita o redirecionamento.

O Parâmetro `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` como `true` para que o resultado não seja despachado diretamente no browser, podendo assim, manipular a string recebida.

```
$c = curl_init();
$cookie_file = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'megasena.txt';
curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena',
    CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Foo Spider',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 6,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 6,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie_file,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie_file
));

try {
    $content = curl_exec($c);
    $data = curl_getinfo($c);
    $data['content'] = $content;
    unset($content);
    $data['errno'] = curl_errno($c);
    $data['errmsg'] = curl_error($c);
    if ((int)$data['errno'] !== 0 || (int)$data['http_code'] !== 200) {
        echo 'error number: '.$data['errno'];
        echo 'error message: '.$data['errmsg'];
        echo 'http status: '.$data['http_code'];
        //print_r($data);
        exit;
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    print_r($ex); exit;
}

curl_close($c); 

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($data['content']);
unset($data);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ul');
$data = null;
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') == 'numbers mega-sena') {
        $data = trim($tag->textContent);
        break;
    }
}
$arr = str_split($data, 2);
print_r($arr);
```

O resultado do jogo está num elemento `<ul>` cuja `class` é `numbers mega-sena`.

A lógica é apenas extrair o que interessa, iterando o objeto `$tags` até encontrar o alvo.

O resultado final será somente os números. Exemplo:

```
304247505558
```

Utilizei o str_split() para separar cada dezena num array, o que retorna isso:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 30
    [1] => 42
    [2] => 47
    [3] => 50
    [4] => 55
    [5] => 58
)
```

Nota: Os números do jogo são do Concurso 1795 (02/03/2016).

Para obter os resultados de jogos anteriores, siga a lógica sugerida no comentário do [@Caffé](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14584/caff%C3%A9).

> No final da página dos resultados de cada tipo de jogo (megasena,
>   lotofácil...) a Caixa disponibiliza um arquivo com o resultado de
>   todos os jogos: Exemplos:
>   loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena e
>   loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/lotofacil. Você pode
>   fazer uma carga inicial destes arquivos para a sua base de dados, e ir
>   atualizando a base usando a API da resposta ou ainda fazendo carga
>   diferencial dos tais arquivos. – Caffé 2/03 às 16:26

Esteja ciente de que o site oficial não fornece, pelo menos desconheço, uma forma adequada de obter os resultados dos jogos.

Isso é o máximo que se pode fazer. Uma gambiarra.

Caso queira extrair outros dados, por exemplo, o número do concurso, valor do prêmio, etc, apenas leia o código HTML gerado pela página alvo. Então crie rotinas para abstrair os dados que deseja, tal como o exemplo demonstra a abstração do número sorteado do jogo.

Saliento que o script é um exemplo com finalidade didática. O trecho com `try/catch` tal como o trecho que identifica retorno de erro e o resultado final, implemente conforme for conveniente para o seu caso.

Importante estar ciente que uma mudança nos códigos da página dos resultados pode afetar o funcionamento. Portanto deve manter-se sempre atento a quaisquer mudanças na página de onde obtém os dados.

Para outros jogos como a Loto fácil, siga a mesma lógica do exemplo.

Answer (score 4):

É possivel obter qualquer resultado de qualquer modalidade de loteria na forma de um JSON, acessando uma simples URL.

Basta acessar diretamente as segintes URLs e será obtido o respectivo resultado do concurso mais recente:

https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/quina
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/megasena
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/duplasena
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/lotofacil
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/lotomania
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/diadesorte
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/timemania
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/federal
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/loteca
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/supersete

Nesse esquema, o JSON do resultado de um determinado concurso poderá ser obtido adicionando-se o número do sorteio desejado ao final da respectiva URL.

P.ex., para se obter o resultado do concurso 1234 da quina, basta um GET em

https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/quina/1234

Comment: Tinha visto isso no console do site da loteria, muito bom vlw