# Obter parte de um site

Tags: php

Bom o que eu intencionava fazer é obter a parte de um site com php e armazenar numa variavel $preço_medio.

Bom o link é o seguinte: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=M249%20|%20Contrast%20Spray%20(Field-Tested)

A partir deste link queria obter o valor de "median_price":"$0.03" e armazenar nessa tal variavel de $preço_medio.

Como poderei o fazer?

Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como posso pegar os resultados das loterias?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47597/como-posso-pegar-os-resultados-das-loterias)

Comment: veja o script dessa resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47605/4793 A lógica é a mesma. Apenas troque a URL

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, pode me dar um exemplo com o código para eu conseguir entender melhor? Obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que seja duplicata exata desta (afinal, só muda a origem dos dados): **[Receber dados de JSON externo por PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4410/receber-dados-de-json-externo-por-php)**.

Answer (score 2):

É possível com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

  $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=M249%20|%20Contrast%20Spray%20(Field-Tested)";  
  $json = file_get_contents($url);  
  $decode = json_decode($json, TRUE);   

  $preco_medio = $decode['median_price'];
?>
```

Ou seja, acessamos a URL com `file_get_contents` e decodificamos o JSON, que se transformará em um *array*. Logo, atribuímos o valor do *array* correspondente ao preço médio à variável que desejar :)

PS: Através de `print_r` é possível visualizar o *array* gerado a partir do JSON para obtermos o valor correto para utilizar nos colchetes

```
print_r ($decode);
```