# Curl - Resultado da mega sena por numero de concurso

Tags: php, libcurl

script by Daniel Omine modificado por mim. Original: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116727/4793

```
 $c = curl_init();
$cookie_file = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'megasena.txt';
curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena',
    CURLOPT_REFERER => 'http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Foo Spider',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 6,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 6,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie_file,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie_file
    ));

try {
    $content = curl_exec($c);
    $data = curl_getinfo($c);
    $data['content'] = $content;
    unset($content);
    $data['errno'] = curl_errno($c);
    $data['errmsg'] = curl_error($c);
    if ((int)$data['errno'] !== 0 || (int)$data['http_code'] !== 200) {
        echo 'error number: '.$data['errno'];
        echo 'error message: '.$data['errmsg'];
        echo 'http status: '.$data['http_code'];
    //print_r($data);
        exit;
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    print_r($ex); exit;
}

curl_close($c); 

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data['content']);
unset($data);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
$dezenas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('ul');
$proximo = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

$data = null;

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') == 'title-bar clearfix') {
        $data = trim($tag->textContent);
        break;
    }
}

foreach ($dezenas as $dez) {
    if ($dez->getAttribute('class') == 'numbers mega-sena') {
        $dataDezenas = trim($dez->textContent);
        break;
    }
}
foreach ($proximo as $prx) {
    if ($prx->getAttribute('class') == 'next-prize clearfix') {
        $proximoPremio = trim($prx->textContent);
        break;
    }
}

$dezenas = str_split($dataDezenas,2);
print 'concuros nº: '.substr($data,42,4)." data:".substr($data,48,10) ;
print '<br />'.substr($proximoPremio,0,54).' '.substr($proximoPremio, 63,16);


print'<pre>';
print_r($dezenas);
print'</pre>';
```

Código funcionando 100%
segue return

```
concuros nº: 1878 data:19/11/2016
Estimativa de prêmio do próximo concurso 23/11/2016 R$ 13.400.000,00

Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 26
    [3] => 40
    [4] => 56
    [5] => 57
)
```

vi que no site http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena
tem uma campo para fazer a busca porem o get da url não segue um padrão, acho que é criptografado.

Exemplo da url com a busca.

Busca por: 1877
url:
http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbwMPI0sDBxNXAOMwrzCjA0sjIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wNnUwNHfxcnSwBgIDUyhCvA5EawAjxsKckMjDDI9FQE-F4ca/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0KO6H80AU71KG7J0072/act/id=0/p=javax.portlet.action=processBusca/341153355272/=/

Busca por: 1876
url:
http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/!ut/p/a1/jY7LDoIwFES_hS_oUKAtywKm5WEgMSiwIYSFIREwvr7fYty4EL2zusmZySENqUgzdY_h2N2GeepOy9-wltkZNBQSxFRAupuC7pO9A-EYoDZAqKR2eQbAFRRxFOiI-1sgZv_18eUkfvUPpPlEVBF6kHkU-HBM4L2BNcUXsOJQG0neapUKWyikOdPGouR2qngCcEp2y0Y_T_39cp1JbQvOyXksKwzFOErLegJXcffd/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0KO6H80AU71KG7J0072/act/id=0/p=javax.portlet.action=processBusca/341153754538/=/#Z7_HGK818G0KO6H80AU71KG7J0072

Tem como fazer essa consulta por concurso através da url?

Parece que mesmo informando a url modificada ele trás o resultado mais recente.

Comment: Isso são tokens de autenticação para impedir consulta por vias terceiras que não sejam autorizadas pelo site. É possível burlar mas não vou compartilhar isso.

Answer (score 2):

Vou estrear aqui dando uma de coveiro, desencavando esse assunto :)

**ATENÇÃO: Veja a última edição desta resposta, no fim do texto.**

Parece ser possível pegar todas as informações, de qualquer concurso, de todas as loterias que a Caixa disponibiliza online (Quina, Mega, Dupla, Lotomania, Lotofácil, Federal, <s>Lotogol,</s> Timemania, Loteca, Dia de Sorte e SuperSete).
O procedimento é o mesmo, independentemente da loteria.
(Os resultados muitíssimo antigos podem não ser completos, tipo concurso 1 da Federal.)

---

<s>1) Faça um GET no endereço do resultado da loteria que vc deseja:</s>

```
http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/quina/
.../landing/megasena/
.../landing/duplasena/
.../landing/lotofacil/
.../landing/lotomania/
.../landing/timemania/
.../landing/federal/
.../landing/loteca/
.../landing/lotogol/
.../landing/diadesorte/
.../landing/supersete
```

(note que não é necessário esperar que os scripts da página sejam baixados e executados)

2. Do arquivo HTML recebido obtenha o tag link que tenha o atributo id="com.ibm.lotus.NavStateUrl"
3. Do tag link acima, obtenha o atributo href
4. Do arquivo HTML recebido obtenha o tag input que tenha o atributo id="urlBuscarResultado"
5. Do tag input acima, obtenha o atributo value
6. Faça um GET para o endereço criado por:
   http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/ +
   href do item 3 + value do item 5 + "?timestampAjax=" + valor em milissegundos
   onde o valor em milissegundos é a quantidade de milissegundos decorridos entre 1 de Janeiro de 1970 00:00:00 UTC e a data atual UTC. Este valor é o fornecido por getTime() do Javascript, por exemplo.
7. Com o GET do passo 6 acima, a Caixa lhe enviará um JSON com todos os dados mais recentes da loteria em questão.
8. Sabendo-se o número específico (xxx) de um concurso, é possível adicionar
   "&concurso=xxx" ao final da URL do passo 6 acima e vc terá todos os dados (em um JSON) do tal concurso.
   Exemplo com a Quina (último resultado):

```
//--------------------------------------------------------
1) GET de http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/quina/
Quina web scrap:
2) Encontrado tag link com id="com.ibm.lotus.NavStateUrl":
3) href=/wps/portal/loterias/landing/quina/!ut/p/a1/jc69DoIwAATgZ_EJepS2wFgoaUswsojYxXQyTfgbjM9vNS4Oordd8l1yxJGBuNnfw9XfwjL78dmduIikhYFGA0tzSFZ3tG_6FCmP4BxBpaVhWQuA5RRWlUZlxR6w4r89vkTi1_5E3CfRXcUhD6osEAHA32Dr4gtsfFin44Bgdw9WWSwj/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2XzYxTDBIMEcwSjBJMjgwQTRFUDJWSlYzMDM1/
4) Encontrado tag input com id="urlBuscarResultado":
5) value=dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_61L0H0G0J0VSC0AC4GLFAD20G6/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/
6) URL para baixar o JSON da Quina (último resultado disponível em 12/08/2019 22:10:21 UTC):
http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/quina/!ut/p/a1/jc69DoIwAATgZ_EJepS2wFgoaUswsojYxXQyTfgbjM9vNS4Oordd8l1yxJGBuNnfw9XfwjL78dmduIikhYFGA0tzSFZ3tG_6FCmP4BxBpaVhWQuA5RRWlUZlxR6w4r89vkTi1_5E3CfRXcUhD6osEAHA32Dr4gtsfFin44Bgdw9WWSwj/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2XzYxTDBIMEcwSjBJMjgwQTRFUDJWSlYzMDM1/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_61L0H0G0J0VSC0AC4GLFAD20G6/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/?timestampAjax=1565647821868  
7) JSON recebido:
{"proximoConcurso":"5043","concursoAnterior":"5042","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"concurso":5043,"data":1565406000000,"resultado":"17-44-70-33-29","ganhadores":1,"ganhadores_quadra":127,"ganhadores_terno":10793,"qt_ganhador_duque":262601,"valor":8083469.71,"valor_quadra":5835.88,"valor_terno":103.26,"vr_rateio_duque":2.33,"no_cidade":"SÃO PAULO","sg_uf":"SP","vrAcumulado":0.00,"vrAcumuladoEspecial":15052634.26,"vrEstimado":600000.00,"dtProximoConcurso":1565578800000,"vrArrecadado":12855120.00,"observacao":null,"de_local_sorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","ic_concurso_especial":false,"resultadoOrdenado":"17-29-33-44-70","duque":"0","error":false,"rateioProcessamento":false,"verificaAcumulado":false,"sorteioAcumulado":false,"localSorteio":"no ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","ganhadoresPorUf":[{"proximoConcurso":null,"concursoAnterior":null,"forward":null,"mensagens":[],"coLoteria":"3","nuConcurso":"5043","sgUf":"BA","qtGanhadores":1,"noCidade":"SALVADOR","total":null,"icCanalEletronico":false}],"quinaSaoJoao":false,"dataStr":"10/08/2019","dtProximoConcursoStr":"12/08/2019"}
```

Exemplo de alguns JSON recebidos para outras loterias:

```
Mega Sena
{"proximoConcurso":"2178","concursoAnterior":"2177","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"concurso":2178,"data":1565406000000,"resultado":"16-21-42-02-50-56","ganhadores":0,"ganhadores_quina":25,"ganhadores_quadra":2304,"valor":0.00,"valor_quina":63031.11,"valor_quadra":977.04,"acumulado":1,"valor_acumulado":5322631.02,"dtinclusao":1565483340000,"prox_final_zero":"2180","ac_final_zero":8965275.73,"proxConcursoFinal":null,"observacao":null,"rowguid":"189BE8BB-3D83-4C0E-B503-E8076AFDBE39","ic_conferido":"1","de_local_sorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","no_cidade":"SÃO PAULO","sg_uf":"SP","vr_estimativa":9000000.00,"dt_proximo_concurso":1565751600000,"vr_acumulado_especial":62264914.37,"vr_arrecadado":27331370.50,"ic_concurso_especial":false,"error":false,"rateioProcessamento":false,"sorteioAcumulado":true,"concursoEspecial":"0","ganhadoresPorUf":null,"resultadoOrdenado":"02-16-21-42-50-56","dataStr":"10/08/2019","dt_proximo_concursoStr":"14/08/2019"}

Dupla Sena
{"proximoConcurso":"1972","concursoAnterior":"1971","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"concurso":1972,"data":1565406000000,"dtinclusao":1565482800000,"resultado_sorteio1":"11-02-06-41-27-14","ganhadores_sena1":0,"valor_sena1":0.00,"acumulado_sena1":"1","valor_acumulado_sena1":1172590.19,"resultado_sorteio2":"48-38-47-25-45-27","ganhadores_sena2":0,"valor_sena2":0.00,"ganhadores_quina2":12,"valor_quina2":3813.31,"ganhadores_quadra2":785,"valor_quadra2":74.02,"observacao":null,"ic_conferido":"1","de_local_sorteio1":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","no_cidade":"SÃO PAULO","sg_uf":"SP","valor_estimativa":1400000.00,"data_proximo_concurso":1565665200000,"vr_arrecadado":1675562.00,"qt_ganhador_quina_faixa1":15,"vr_quina_faixa1":3389.61,"qt_ganhador_quadra_faixa1":798,"vr_quadra_faixa1":72.81,"vr_acumulado_especial":4801067.87,"qt_ganhador_terno_faixa1":14580,"vr_terno_faixa1":1.99,"qt_ganhador_terno_faixa2":14172,"vr_terno_faixa2":2.05,"ic_concurso_especial":false,"error":false,"acumulado":true,"previaNormal":false,"previaEspecial":false,"ganhadoresPorRegiao1":[],"ganhadoresPorRegiao2":[],"resultadoOrdenadoSorteio1":"02-06-11-14-27-41","resultadoOrdenadoSorteio2":"25-27-38-45-47-48","data_proximo_concursoStr":"13/08/2019","dataStr":"10/08/2019","descricaoLocalSorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA"}

Lotofácil
{"proximoConcurso":"1851","concursoAnterior":"1850","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"nu_concurso":"1851","dt_apuracao":1565319600000,"de_resultado":"10-19-01-20-16-05-25-13-23-22-06-11-07-08-09","de_observacao":null,"qt_ganhador_faixa1":1,"qt_ganhador_faixa2":355,"qt_ganhador_faixa3":15157,"qt_ganhador_faixa4":207380,"qt_ganhador_faixa5":1230670,"vr_rateio_faixa1":2535410.34,"vr_rateio_faixa2":2197.54,"vr_rateio_faixa3":20.00,"vr_rateio_faixa4":8.00,"vr_rateio_faixa5":4.00,"no_cidade":"SÃO PAULO","sg_uf":"SP","vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"0,00","vrAcumuladoFaixa2":"0,00","vrEstimativa":"2.000.000,00","dtProximoConcurso":1565578800000,"vrArrecadado":"28.736.786,00","vrAcumuladoEspecial":"67.030.126,61","de_local_sorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","ic_concurso_especial":false,"sorteioAcumulado":false,"rateioProcessamento":false,"localSorteio":"no ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","ganhadoresPorUf":[{"proximoConcurso":null,"concursoAnterior":null,"forward":null,"mensagens":[],"coLoteria":"T","nuConcurso":"1851","sgUf":"RS","qtGanhadores":1,"noCidade":"BENTO GONÇALVES","total":null,"icCanalEletronico":false}],"error":false,"resultadoOrdenado":"01-05-06-07-08-09-10-11-13-16-19-20-22-23-25","dt_apuracaoStr":"09/08/2019","dtProximoConcursoStr":"12/08/2019"}

Lotomania
{"proximoConcurso":"1994","concursoAnterior":"1993","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"concurso":1994,"dtApuracao":1565319600000,"deObservacao":null,"deResultado":"37 - 02 - 21 - 16 - 42 - 90 - 26 - 44 - 03 - 34 - 85 - 95 - 86 - 92 - 60 - 07 - 71 - 88 - 50 - 04","qtGanhadoresFaixa1":0,"qtGanhadoresFaixa2":3,"qtGanhadoresFaixa3":61,"qtGanhadoresFaixa4":726,"qtGanhadoresFaixa5":4409,"qtGanhadoresFaixa6":0,"qtGanhadoresFaixa7":20201,"vrRateioFaixa1":0.00,"vrRateioFaixa2":68623.28,"vrRateioFaixa3":2109.32,"vrRateioFaixa4":177.22,"vrRateioFaixa5":29.18,"vrRateioFaixa6":0.00,"vrRateioFaixa7":6.36,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":681943.84,"vrAcumuladoFaixa2":0.00,"vrAcumuladoFaixa3":0.00,"vrAcumuladoFaixa4":0.00,"vrAcumuladoFaixa5":0.00,"vrAcumuladoFaixa6":0.00,"vrAcumuladoFaixa7":0.00,"dtInclusao":1565394240000,"icConferido":"1","icLocalSorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","noCidade":"SÃO PAULO","sgUf":"SP","vrEstimativa":1300000.00,"dtProximoConcurso":1565665200000,"vrArrecadado":4240263.00,"vrAcumuladoEspecial":0.00,"totalAcumulado":"681.943,84","sorteioAcumulado":true,"error":false,"rateioProcessamento":false,"acumuladoPascoa":false,"localSorteio":"no ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","ganhadoresPorRegiao1":null,"ganhadoresPorRegiao2":null,"resultadoOrdenado":"02-03-04-07-16-21-26-34-37-42-44-50-60-71-85-86-88-90-92-95","dtApuracaoStr":"09/08/2019","dtProximoConcursoStr":"13/08/2019","especialPascoa":false}

Dia de Sorte
{"proximoConcurso":"187","concursoAnterior":"186","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"de_local_sorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","error":false,"sorteioAcumulado":false,"rateioProcessamento":false,"localSorteio":"no ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","legendaFinal":null,"ganhadoresPorUf":[{"proximoConcurso":null,"concursoAnterior":null,"forward":null,"mensagens":[],"coLoteria":"S","nuConcurso":"187","sgUf":"PI","qtGanhadores":1,"noCidade":"FRONTEIRAS","total":null,"icCanalEletronico":false},{"proximoConcurso":null,"concursoAnterior":null,"forward":null,"mensagens":[],"coLoteria":"S","nuConcurso":"187","sgUf":"XX","qtGanhadores":1,"noCidade":"Canal Eletrônico","total":null,"icCanalEletronico":true}],"resultadoOrdenado":"01-03-06-15-17-23-26","nu_CONCURSO":"187","de_RESULTADO":"01-15-06-26-03-23-17","de_OBSERVACAO":null,"sg_UF":"SP","no_CIDADE":"SÃO PAULO","qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_1":"2","vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_1":145273.65,"qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_2":151,"vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_2":1178.05,"qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_3":4865,"vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_3":20.00,"qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_4":40213,"vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_4":4.00,"vr_ACUMULADO":0.00,"vr_ESTIMATIVA":300000.00,"ic_CONFERIDO":"1","vr_ARRECADADO":2596190.00,"dt_APURACAO":1565406000000,"dt_APURACAOStr":"10/08/2019","dt_PROXIMO_CONCURSO":1565665200000,"dt_PROXIMO_CONCURSOStr":"13/08/2019","mes_DE_SORTE":10,"qt_GANHADOR_MES_DE_SORTE":137162,"vr_RATEIO_MES_DE_SORTE":2.00}

Timemania
{"proximoConcurso":"1368","concursoAnterior":"1367","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"de_local_sorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","error":false,"sorteioAcumulado":true,"rateioProcessamento":false,"localSorteio":"no ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA","legendaFinal":"zero","timeCoracao":"ATHLÉTICO/PR","ganhadoresPorUf":null,"resultadoOrdenado":"21-39-50-55-64-71-78","nu_CONCURSO":"1368","de_RESULTADO":"71-39-64-78-21-55-50","de_OBSERVACAO":null,"sg_UF":"SP","no_CIDADE":"SÃO PAULO","co_TIME_CORACAO":"12","qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_1":"0","vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_1":0.00,"qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_2":0,"vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_2":0.00,"qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_3":66,"vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_3":1163.85,"qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_4":1456,"vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_4":6.00,"qt_GANHADOR_FAIXA_5":14332,"vr_RATEIO_FAIXA_5":2.00,"qt_GANHADOR_TIME_CORACAO":"6722","vr_RATEIO_TIME_CORACAO":5.00,"vr_ACUMULADO_FAIXA_1":321601.59,"vr_ESTIMATIVA_FAIXA_1":450000.00,"nu_PROXIMO_CONCURSO_FINAL_0_5":"1370","vr_ACUMULADO_PROXIMO_CONCURSO":242285.96,"nu_CONFIGURACAO":"4","ic_CONFERIDO":"1","vr_ACUMULADO_FAIXA_2":0.00,"vr_ACUMULADO_FAIXA_3":0.00,"vr_ARRECADADO":989310.00,"dt_APURACAO":1565406000000,"dt_APURACAOStr":"10/08/2019","dt_PROXIMO_CONCURSO":1565665200000,"dt_PROXIMO_CONCURSOStr":"13/08/2019"}

Federal
{"concursoAnterior":"05412","premios":[{"proximoConcurso":"05414","concursoAnterior":"05412","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"extracao":"05413","planoSorteio":"639","dataExtracao":"10/08/2019","premio1":"11653","premio2":"38114","premio3":"77374","premio4":"69582","premio5":"56675","observacao":"","informacao":null,"icLocalSorteio":"","noCidade":"SAO PAULO","sgUf":"SP","faixa":"001","valor":"1.350.000,00","series":null,"tipoPlano":"N","co_bilhete":null,"qtde_bilhetes":"90000","error":false,"bilhete":"11653"},{"proximoConcurso":"05414","concursoAnterior":"05412","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"extracao":"05413","planoSorteio":"639","dataExtracao":"10/08/2019","premio1":"11653","premio2":"38114","premio3":"77374","premio4":"69582","premio5":"56675","observacao":"","informacao":null,"icLocalSorteio":"","noCidade":"SAO PAULO","sgUf":"SP","faixa":"002","valor":"15.500,00","series":null,"tipoPlano":"N","co_bilhete":null,"qtde_bilhetes":"90000","error":false,"bilhete":"38114"},{"proximoConcurso":"05414","concursoAnterior":"05412","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"extracao":"05413","planoSorteio":"639","dataExtracao":"10/08/2019","premio1":"11653","premio2":"38114","premio3":"77374","premio4":"69582","premio5":"56675","observacao":"","informacao":null,"icLocalSorteio":"","noCidade":"SAO PAULO","sgUf":"SP","faixa":"003","valor":"14.000,00","series":null,"tipoPlano":"N","co_bilhete":null,"qtde_bilhetes":"90000","error":false,"bilhete":"77374"},{"proximoConcurso":"05414","concursoAnterior":"05412","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"extracao":"05413","planoSorteio":"639","dataExtracao":"10/08/2019","premio1":"11653","premio2":"38114","premio3":"77374","premio4":"69582","premio5":"56675","observacao":"","informacao":null,"icLocalSorteio":"","noCidade":"SAO PAULO","sgUf":"SP","faixa":"004","valor":"13.000,00","series":null,"tipoPlano":"N","co_bilhete":null,"qtde_bilhetes":"90000","error":false,"bilhete":"69582"},{"proximoConcurso":"05414","concursoAnterior":"05412","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"extracao":"05413","planoSorteio":"639","dataExtracao":"10/08/2019","premio1":"11653","premio2":"38114","premio3":"77374","premio4":"69582","premio5":"56675","observacao":"","informacao":null,"icLocalSorteio":"","noCidade":"SAO PAULO","sgUf":"SP","faixa":"005","valor":"12.227,00","series":null,"tipoPlano":"N","co_bilhete":null,"qtde_bilhetes":"90000","error":false,"bilhete":"56675"}],"cidade":"SAO PAULO","observacao":"","proximoConcurso":"05414","data":"10/08/2019","concurso":"05413","ufSorteio":"SP"}

Loteca
{"proximoConcurso":null,"concursoAnterior":"862","forward":null,"mensagens":[],"concurso":863,"dtApuracao":1565578800000,"icJogo":"1","dt_jogo":1565406000000,"noTime1":"SÃO PAULO/SP","noTime2":"SANTOS/SP","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","qtGanhadorFaixa2":"104","qtGanhadorFaixa3":null,"vrRateioFaixa1":0.00,"vrRateioFaixa2":1105.48,"vrRateioFaixa3":null,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":666387.41,"vrConcursoAcumulado":310747.13,"nuConcursoAcumulado":"865","vrEstimativa":1100000.00,"vrArrecadado":2038062.00,"qt_gol_time1":"3","qt_gol_time2":"2","de_observacao":null,"dt_proximo_concurso":1566183600000,"ic_sorteio":"0","jogos":[{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"1","dt_jogo":1565406000000,"noTime1":"SÃO PAULO/SP","noTime2":"SANTOS/SP","qt_gol_time1":"3","qt_gol_time2":"2","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Sábado","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"2","dt_jogo":1565406000000,"noTime1":"FLAMENGO/RJ","noTime2":"GRÊMIO/RS","qt_gol_time1":"3","qt_gol_time2":"1","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Sábado","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"3","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"AVAÍ/SC","noTime2":"CRUZEIRO/MG","qt_gol_time1":"2","qt_gol_time2":"2","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":false,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":true},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"4","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"INTERNACIONAL/RS","noTime2":"CORINTHIANS/SP","qt_gol_time1":"0","qt_gol_time2":"0","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":false,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":true},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"5","dt_jogo":1565406000000,"noTime1":"CEARÁ/CE","noTime2":"CHAPECOENSE/SC","qt_gol_time1":"4","qt_gol_time2":"1","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Sábado","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"6","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"BOTAFOGO/RJ","noTime2":"ATHLÉTICO/PR","qt_gol_time1":"2","qt_gol_time2":"1","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"7","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"PALMEIRAS/SP","noTime2":"BAHIA/BA","qt_gol_time1":"2","qt_gol_time2":"2","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":false,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":true},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"8","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"GOIÁS/GO","noTime2":"VASCO DA GAMA/RJ","qt_gol_time1":"0","qt_gol_time2":"1","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":false,"colunaDois":true,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"9","dt_jogo":1565406000000,"noTime1":"CORITIBA/PR","noTime2":"FIGUEIRENSE/SC","qt_gol_time1":"2","qt_gol_time2":"0","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Sábado","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"10","dt_jogo":1565406000000,"noTime1":"VITÓRIA/BA","noTime2":"PARANÁ/PR","qt_gol_time1":"2","qt_gol_time2":"0","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Sábado","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"11","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"CRICIÚMA/SC","noTime2":"SPORT/PE","qt_gol_time1":"1","qt_gol_time2":"0","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"12","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"PONTE PRETA/SP","noTime2":"GUARANI/SP","qt_gol_time1":"1","qt_gol_time2":"0","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"13","dt_jogo":1565492400000,"noTime1":"CONFIANÇA/SE","noTime2":"SANTA CRUZ/PE","qt_gol_time1":"1","qt_gol_time2":"1","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Domingo","colunaUm":false,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":true},{"concurso":863,"icJogo":"14","dt_jogo":1565406000000,"noTime1":"ATLÉTICO/MG","noTime2":"FLUMINENSE/RJ","qt_gol_time1":"2","qt_gol_time2":"1","dtApuracao":1565578800000,"vrAcumuladoFaixa1":"666.387,41","qtGanhadorFaixa1":"0","diaDaSemana":"Sábado","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false}],"error":false,"sorteioAcumulado":true,"sorteioAcumuladoCinco":true,"rateioProcessamento":false,"localSorteio":null,"legendaFinal":null,"ganhadoresPorUf":[],"ultimoConcurso":true,"dtApuracaoStr":"12/08/2019","dt_proximo_concursoStr":"19/08/2019","colunaUm":true,"colunaDois":false,"colunaMeio":false,"concursosProgramacao":null}

SuperSete
{"tipoJogo":"SUPER_SETE","numero":66,"nomeMunicipioUFSorteio":"SAO PAULO, SP","dataApuracao":"12/03/2021","valorArrecadado":1123380.00,"valorEstimadoProximoConcurso":3400000.00,"valorAcumuladoProximoConcurso":3227042.20,"valorAcumuladoConcursoEspecial":0.00,"valorAcumuladoConcurso_0_5":0.00,"acumulado":true,"indicadorConcursoEspecial":1,"dezenasSorteadasOrdemSorteio":["008","006","008","009","009","005","000"],"listaResultadoEquipeEsportiva":null,"numeroJogo":7,"nomeTimeCoracaoMesSorte":null,"tipoPublicacao":3,"observacao":"","localSorteio":"Espaço Loterias CAIXA                   ","dataProximoConcurso":"15/03/2021","numeroConcursoAnterior":65,"numeroConcursoProximo":67,"valorTotalPremioFaixaUm":3227042.20,"numeroConcursoFinal_0_5":0,"listaMunicipioUFGanhadores":[],"listaRateioPremio":[{"faixa":1,"numeroDeGanhadores":0,"valorPremio":0.00,"descricaoFaixa":"7 acertos"},{"faixa":2,"numeroDeGanhadores":1,"valorPremio":46327.60,"descricaoFaixa":"6 acertos"},{"faixa":3,"numeroDeGanhadores":56,"valorPremio":1181.82,"descricaoFaixa":"5 acertos"},{"faixa":4,"numeroDeGanhadores":1055,"valorPremio":62.73,"descricaoFaixa":"4 acertos"},{"faixa":5,"numeroDeGanhadores":9154,"valorPremio":5.00,"descricaoFaixa":"3 acertos"}],"listaDezenas":["008","006","008","009","009","005","000"],"listaDezenasSegundoSorteio":null,"id":null}

Dia de Sorte
{"tipoJogo":"DIA_DE_SORTE","numero":429,"nomeMunicipioUFSorteio":"SÃO PAULO, SP","dataApuracao":"11/03/2021","valorArrecadado":1962332.00,"valorEstimadoProximoConcurso":1400000.00,"valorAcumuladoProximoConcurso":1134828.92,"valorAcumuladoConcursoEspecial":0.00,"valorAcumuladoConcurso_0_5":0.00,"acumulado":true,"indicadorConcursoEspecial":1,"dezenasSorteadasOrdemSorteio":["017","027","015","008","023","019","031"],"listaResultadoEquipeEsportiva":null,"numeroJogo":11,"nomeTimeCoracaoMesSorte":"Setembro         ","tipoPublicacao":3,"observacao":"","localSorteio":"ESPAÇO LOTERIAS CAIXA                   ","dataProximoConcurso":"13/03/2021","numeroConcursoAnterior":428,"numeroConcursoProximo":430,"valorTotalPremioFaixaUm":0,"numeroConcursoFinal_0_5":0,"listaMunicipioUFGanhadores":[],"listaRateioPremio":[{"faixa":1,"numeroDeGanhadores":0,"valorPremio":0.00,"descricaoFaixa":"7 acertos"},{"faixa":2,"numeroDeGanhadores":81,"valorPremio":1857.97,"descricaoFaixa":"6 acertos"},{"faixa":3,"numeroDeGanhadores":2197,"valorPremio":20.00,"descricaoFaixa":"5 acertos"},{"faixa":4,"numeroDeGanhadores":26732,"valorPremio":4.00,"descricaoFaixa":"4 acertos"},{"faixa":5,"numeroDeGanhadores":99075,"valorPremio":2.00,"descricaoFaixa":"Mês da Sorte"}],"listaDezenas":["008","015","017","019","023","027","031"],"listaDezenasSegundoSorteio":null,"id":null}
```

Como mencionado anteriormente, posso pegar o resultado do concurso no. 1 da Quina, adicionando "&concurso=1" à URL que usei para baixar o resultado mais recente.

http://www.loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/quina/!ut/p/a1/jc69DoIwAATgZ_EJepS2wFgoaUswsojYxXQyTfgbjM9vNS4Oordd8l1yxJGBuNnfw9XfwjL78dmduIikhYFGA0tzSFZ3tG_6FCmP4BxBpaVhWQuA5RRWlUZlxR6w4r89vkTi1_5E3CfRXcUhD6osEAHA32Dr4gtsfFin44Bgdw9WWSwj/dl5/d5/L2dJQSEvUUt3QS80SmlFL1o2XzYxTDBIMEcwSjBJMjgwQTRFUDJWSlYzMDM1/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_61L0H0G0J0VSC0AC4GLFAD20G6/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/?timestampAjax=1565647821868&concurso=1

JSON do concurso 1 da Quina:

```
{"proximoConcurso":"2","concursoAnterior":null,"forward":null,"mensagens":[],"concurso":1,"data":763527600000,"resultado":"25-45-60-76-79","ganhadores":3,"ganhadores_quadra":127,"ganhadores_terno":7030,"qt_ganhador_duque":null,"valor":75731225.00,"valor_quadra":1788927.00,"valor_terno":42982.00,"vr_rateio_duque":null,"no_cidade":null,"sg_uf":null,"vrAcumulado":0.00,"vrAcumuladoEspecial":null,"vrEstimado":0.00,"dtProximoConcurso":null,"vrArrecadado":null,"observacao":"","de_local_sorteio":null,"ic_concurso_especial":false,"resultadoOrdenado":"25-45-60-76-79","duque":"1","error":false,"rateioProcessamento":false,"verificaAcumulado":false,"sorteioAcumulado":false,"localSorteio":null,"ganhadoresPorUf":null,"quinaSaoJoao":false,"dataStr":"13/03/1994","dtProximoConcursoStr":null}
```

Vale lembrar que a Caixa, normalmente, disponibiliza todos os resultados em arquivos compactados (ZIP), mas os atualiza com um certo atraso.
O link costuma ficar em "Download de todos os resultados" na página do resultado de uma loteria.

Espero ter conseguido responder à pergunta
*Tem como fazer essa consulta por concurso através da url?*

<s>Editado em 13/03/2021:
Atenção: A Caixa mudou recentemente o conteúdo do JSON enviado, mas o procedimento para obtê-lo continua o mesmo.
Inclusive para a loteria Supersete.</s>

**Editado em 10/03/2022:**
A CEF alterou o esquema para obtenção dos JSONs dos resultados de loteria.
Agora basta acessar diretamente as segintes URLs e será obtido o respectivo resultado do concurso mais recente:

https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/quina
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/megasena
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/duplasena
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/lotofacil
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/lotomania
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/diadesorte
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/timemania
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/federal
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/loteca
https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/supersete

Nesse esquema, o JSON do resultado de um determinado concurso poderá ser obtido adicionando-se o número do sorteio desejado ao final da respectiva URL.

P.ex., para se obter o resultado do concurso 1234 da quina, basta um GET em

https://servicebus2.caixa.gov.br/portaldeloterias/api/quina/1234