# Web scraping python executando javascript no site da CEF

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

A CEF(Caixa Econômica Federal) mudou a forma como exibe os resultados das loterias em seu site, antes eu conseguia pegar os resultados que vinham todos no HTML via webscraping de forma relativamente fácil usando o BealtfulSoup, mas agora esses resultados são exibidos executando via browser javascript. Busquei na net algumas coisas mas não consegui entender o processo em si. Se alguem puder me ajudar, agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se possível poste o código que você já tentou.

Comment: Veja a minha resposta a https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/167345/curl-resultado-da-mega-sena-por-numero-de-concurso

Answer (score 1):

O próprio site da caixa disponibiliza o download de todos os resultados em formato html. Nesta página lá em baixo é possível fazer o download `http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena`
, porém se for por motivos didáticos, você tem duas alternativas, uma é explorar o endpoint que o javascript busca

```
http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbwMPI0sDBxNXAOMwrzCjA0sjIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wNnUwNHfxcnSwBgIDUyhCvA5EawAjxsKckMjDDI9FQE-F4ca/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0KO6H80AU71KG7J0072/res/id=buscaResultado/c=cacheLevelPage/=/?timestampAjax=1528262624920
```

Que o único parâmetro é a timestamp no final.

Outra alternativa é utilizar a biblioteca selenium e renderizar o javascript e depois, passar o javascript já renderizado para o beautiful soup por exemplo.

Comment: vlw mano, consigo baixar esses arquivos, inclusive os jogo no banco de dados para estatísticas. Ocorre que no site da caixa sai os dados bem atual em algumas horas depois dos sorteios, o que não ocorre com os arquivos dos jogos baixados que não ficam atualizados.

Comment: Vou dar uma aprofundada no Selenium pra ver se consigo renderizar o javascript, olhei mais superficialmente e não consegui desvendar para trazer o resultado completo com os números sorteados, qtde de ganhadores e valor de cada faixa.

Comment: o link q coloquei retorna o resultado do último jogo no json 'resultado":"18-19-44-54-01-29', no campo resultado. Enfim, se minha respota o ajudou a marque como correta. obrigado.

Comment: Como vc conseguiu o link com o resultado?, realmente ele tem tudo em um dicionário.

Comment: No próprio console do desenvolvedor, como é ajax, ele tem de fazer uma requisição get no srevidor. de um json ou xml, para poder popular a tabela. Olhe as requisições que forma feitas na página que você vai achar.

Answer (score 1):

A URL "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias" ainda disponibiliza em seu conteúdo `HTML` os ultimos resultados das loterias, e voce pode extraí-los da seguinte forma:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get( "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias" )

soup = BeautifulSoup( req.content, "html.parser" )

ul = soup.findAll( "ul", class_="resultado-loteria mega-sena" )

for li in ul[0].findAll( "li" ):
    print( li.text )
```

Segue uma função capaz de recuperar os resultados da `Mega Sena` usando o `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def obterDezenasMegaSena():
    try:
        req = requests.get( "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias" )
        soup = BeautifulSoup( req.content, "html.parser" )
        ul = soup.findAll( "ul", class_="resultado-loteria mega-sena" )
        return [ int(li.text) for li in ul[0].findAll( "li" ) ]
    except:
        return None

print( obterDezenasMegaSena() )
```

Saída:

```
[3, 6, 11, 27, 28, 46]
```

O mesmo pode ser feito para se extrair as dezenas sorteadas da `Quina`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def obterDezenasQuina():
    try:
        req = requests.get( "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias" )
        soup = BeautifulSoup( req.content, "html.parser" )
        ul = soup.findAll( "ul", class_="resultado-loteria quina" )
        return [ int(li.text) for li in ul[0].findAll( "li" ) ]
    except:
        return None

print( obterDezenasQuina() )
```

Saída:

```
[21, 25, 40, 66, 67]
```

Comment: obrigado amigo, realmente consigo o resultado dos números sorteados, mas preciso de todo o resultado com a qtde de sorteados e o valor para cada faixa e isso só se obtêm executando o javascript.

Comment: @MJAGO: Acho que entendi. Vide minha outra resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o site "http://www.loteriaseresultados.com.br/" para extrair todas as informações sobre todos os sorteios das loterias da CEF usando o `BeautifulSoup`, veja só:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def obterPremiacaoMegaSena( soup, premio ):
    td = soup.find( 'th', text=lambda x: x.startswith(premio)).find_parent('tr').findAll("td")
    if( td[1].text == "-" ):
        return { "Tipo" : premio, "QtdGanhadores" : u"0", "ValorPremio" : u"0,00" }
    else:
        return { "Tipo" : premio, "QtdGanhadores" : td[0].text.split(' ')[0], "ValorPremio" : td[1].text.split(' ')[1] }


def obterResultadoMegaSena( nconcurso ):
    try:
        req = requests.get( "http://www.loteriaseresultados.com.br/megasena/concurso/" + str(nconcurso) )
        soup = BeautifulSoup( req.content, "html.parser" )
        dezenas = [ int(dezena.text) for dezena in soup.findAll( "div", class_="bola bg-success" ) ]
        sena = obterPremiacaoMegaSena( soup, "SENA" )
        quina = obterPremiacaoMegaSena( soup, "QUINA" )
        quadra = obterPremiacaoMegaSena( soup, "QUADRA" )
        return { "Concurso" : nconcurso, "DezenasSorteadas" : dezenas, "Premiacao" : [ sena, quadra, quina ] }
    except:
        return None

print( obterResultadoMegaSena( 2047 ) )
```

Saída:

```
{
  'Concurso': 2047,
  'DezenasSorteadas': [1, 18, 19, 29, 44, 54],
  'Premiacao': [ {
                   'ValorPremio': u'0,00',
                   'QtdGanhadores': u'0',
                   'Tipo': 'SENA'
                 },
                 { 
                   'ValorPremio': u'1.002,65',
                   'QtdGanhadores': u'2.390',
                   'Tipo': 'QUADRA'
                 },
                 { 
                   'ValorPremio': u'55.914,69',
                   'QtdGanhadores': u'30',
                   'Tipo': 'QUINA'
                 }
               ]
}
```